# Is it possible to backup and restore InnoDB tables on Oracle's MySQL 5.7.19 Server with Percona Xtrabackup?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona, backup, xtrabackup

I have the next configuration:

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04.2 x86_64
MySQL Server: Ver 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu)) installed from Ubuntu's repos

**Percona Tools**: innobackupex version 2.4.8 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 97330f7) installed from the Percona's repos.

The problem is the next: When I do the backup with innobackupex and then restore - my InnoDB tables got corrupted.

```
2017-07-28T15:49:50.078080Z 4 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table forum/domain from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
```

The backup/restore happens on the same server. MySQL server has the defaults settings, `innodb_file_per_table` option is not set directly, but Oracle's MySQL has that enabled by the default.

```
mysql> show variables like '%innodb_file%';
+--------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name            | Value     |
+--------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_file_format       | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_format_check | ON        |
| innodb_file_format_max   | Barracuda |
| innodb_file_per_table    | ON        |
+--------------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In order to do the backup, I do:

```
innobackupex --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf \
--include=forum.* --parallel=9 \
--extra-lsndir=/home/forum \
--stream=xbstream \
--no-timestamp /home/forum 2>/home/backup.log | lzop -c > /home/forum.xbs.lzo
```

the `xtrabackup_info` file from the result:

```
uuid = 850f3d9e-73ab-11e7-8b45-448a5b2c32e7
name =
tool_name = innobackupex
tool_command = --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf --include=forum.* --parallel=9 --extra-lsndir=/home/forum --stream=xbstream --no-timestamp /home/forum
tool_version = 2.4.8
ibbackup_version = 2.4.8
server_version = 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
start_time = 2017-07-28 17:43:27
end_time = 2017-07-28 17:43:36
lock_time = 0
binlog_pos =
innodb_from_lsn = 0
innodb_to_lsn = 14341896999
partial = Y
incremental = N
format = xbstream
compact = N
compressed = N
encrypted = N
```

As the restore, I do the next:
unarchive the file:

```
lzop -dcfU /home/forum.xbs.lzo | xbstream -x --directory=/home/forum.restore
```

Apply Log:

```
innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only /home/forum.restore --use-memory=1G 2>/home/restore.log
```

Prepare the backup for usage:

```
innobackupex --apply-log /home/forum.restore --use-memory=1G 2>>/home/restore.log
```

After that my directory has:

```
root@restore-test /home/forum.restore # tree
.
├── backup-my.cnf
├── forum
│   ├── db.opt
│   ├── domain.frm
│   └── domain.ibd
├── ib_buffer_pool
├── ibdata1
├── ib_logfile0
├── ib_logfile1
├── ibtmp1
├── xtrabackup_checkpoints
├── xtrabackup_info
└── xtrabackup_logfile
```

The final is:

1. stop MySQL server
2. `chown -R mysql:mysql /home/forum.restore/forum`
3. `mv /home/forum.restore/forum /var/lib/mysql/forum`
4. start MySQL

The database is there, but when i try to do any operation with the table (SHOW/DESCRIBE/etc) - I'm having the error listed above.

Comment: I posted the same question at Percona's forum: https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtrabackup/49221-is-it-possible-to-backup-and-restore-innodb-tables-on-oracle-s-mysql-5-7-19-server

Comment: Andrey, instead of using `--include=forum.*` can you try `--databases=forum` instead. On that note, please upload the backup and prepare logs in the forums page if not possible here.

Comment: The backup with the same utillities, but without --include=.... parameters works fine and restore works fine as well. But I cannot skip other databases which exist on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and re-reading the manuals I found the next:

1. I had done so called partial backups, that mean that the restore process is a little bit different - you need to specify `--export` option when doing the restore process (see [Restoring Individual Tables](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/innobackupex/restoring_individual_tables_ibk.html))

   - If you are on Percona Server you can try to use `innodb_expand_import` option and avoid of some routine operations.
   - If you are on MySQL server - you **must** also to do the schema dumps. Then do the tricks with `ALTER TABLE xxx DISCARD TABLESPACE` and `ALTER TABLE xxx IMPORT TABLESPACE` for an every single table. ([See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transportable-tablespace-examples.html))
2. I did the restore without specifying the `--export`, so had the problems with those `.frm`'s.
3. If you have stored procedures/etc - maybe you need to backup them as well. I have no chance to check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup database forum and all of its tables you should use this 'simplified' command:

```
innobackupex --databases="forum mysql" --user=root --password='secretPassword' /path/to/backup
```

We recommend to start using xtrabackup instead of innobackupex:

```
xtrabackup --databases="forum mysql" --backup --user=root --password='secretPassword' --target-dir=/path/to/backup
```

To prepare the backup:

```
innobackupex --apply-log /path/to/backup

xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/path/to/backup
```

You need to include the "mysql" database every time you backup.

Comment: The problem is that I need to restore on a different server which already has its own MySQL db.